# importing app css in Django

Tags: css, django, django-templates, static-files

I not sure how to include css to my html. I have an app in my project that has it's own template folder. I want to get the `sample.css` into my html.

Something in the lines of `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{%  %}">`

Not really sure what to put in between `{%  %}`

structure:

```
/proj
   /app
      /templates
         sample.css
         sample.html
```

Here is my template_dirs:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'home/templates'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'gallery/templates'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'contact/templates'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'aboutme/templates'),
)
```

If any other info is required. Please let me know!

**updated struture**

```
/proj
   /app
      /static
         /css
            sample.css
      /templates
         sample.html
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`css` files, as well as `js` files and images, are considered [`static files`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/).

The usual approach is to use `django.contrib.staticfiles` built-in django app to manage static files.

If you set up the app correctly this is how your `link` would look like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'sample.css' %}">
```

Comment: @Liondancer  Also you should put `css` files in other folder. Its a common pattern to put them in a folder called `app/static/css`.

Comment: @RaydelMiranda so rename my template to static?

Comment: @Liondancer don't mix up `templates` and `static files`. These are two complete separate parts of your app. Templates live in `templates` directory, static files live in `static` directory.

Comment: @alecxe i think i understand where you are getting at. Thanks!

Comment: @Liondancer no. Right now you have yuor `css` file in: `/app/templates/sample.css`. I meant you cuold have it in: `/app/static/sample.css`. This will help you when you setup the configuration for Django serving static files.

Comment: @Liondancer have your html files in templates folder and your css files in static/css folder. Similarily js files will reside in /static/js

Comment: @crozzfire yeah, this is even better, but, for starters, the OP should at least separate templates and static files and configure it to work. You know, making it work for the first time could be challenging.

Comment: @Liondancer, what are you waiting for!? This looks as a solid answer to me. ;)

Comment: @alecxe i made a static and template folder inside my app. Because these templates pertain to the app. I have another template folder that doesnt really relate to a specific app

Answer (score 2):

as @alecxe mentions, have them in a folder named static and include these in your settings file.

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)
```